# Message not defined, discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i made some code for a special bot for my Fallout based server, but the bot doesnt go online

what i made is:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    if (message.content === 'hi') {
    message.channel.send('Hi u have no friends lmao');
}
});
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);
});
client.login('YOURTOKENHERE');
}``
```

Answer (score 0):

Message object its result of `client.on 'message'` block. So state `client.on 'ready'` has no message object.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {

});
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);
    if (message.content === 'hi') {
        message.channel.send('Hi u have no friends lmao');
    }
});

client.login('YOURTOKENHERE');
```

Comment: the error i got after fixing the bug was
ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thhda\Desktop\Nuka Caps2\index.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Comment: Hmm, this error you got when bot start, or when you write message ? @MeeuwSoft

Comment: when i try to start the bot, with node index.js, the bot wont go online either

Comment: Are you require Discord.js in header of file? @MeeuwSoft